# accessing public tweets with json

Tags: jquery, json

im trying to access database of twitter using json and jquery(only public tweets). I wrote a function. Here it is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
alert("1");
$("button").click (function(){
    alert("2");
    $.getJSON("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=messi", function(data){
        alert("3");
    });
    alert("4");
});
```

}
after page is loaded an alert appears and says 1, as expected. when i click the button two alerts appear and say 2, 4 respectively. It seems there is a problem with getJSON function i could not solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code infringes the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) by making a cross-domain request.

You can fix that by making it a [JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about) request - which is not an Ajax request and not subject to the Same Origin Policy - by adding a `callback=?` parameter to the query string:

```
$.getJSON("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=messi&callback=?", function(data){
    alert("3");
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MsLT8/)

[`jQuery.getJSON` reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

When the request URL contains the `callback=?` parameter jQuery automatically assumes it as JSONP request and adds this abstraction layer which makes it "look like" an Ajax request. You can work with the `data` object which contains the parsed JSONP response.

ps. You may want to take a look at [Dev Tools'](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) (or [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/)'s) `console` for development. It is non-blocking unlike `alert` and lets you display various data types and nested data structures.